# Is there a kind of library for inputting values into arrays randomly in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

Just like in Java , (Math . random * ) statement is there a way to input array numbers in C++ ?

For example I want to input numbers from 6 to 89 with RANDOM numbers in C++. Assign them into arrays.

I know how to sort the numbers but I would just like to know the method to do random numbers to make my life easier.

I am rusty in programming and I am open to any criticism but I would appreciate a straightforward response.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/rand/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `srand` to seed the random number generator, then use `rand` to get a random number.

For example, the following program populates an array with rando values in your requested range:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main (void) {
    int xyzzy[10];

    // Seed the generator.

    std::srand (time (0));

    // Populate the array.

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(xyzzy) / sizeof(*xyzzy); i++)
        xyzzy[i] = 6 + (std::rand() % 84);

    // Print the array.

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(xyzzy) / sizeof(*xyzzy); i++)
        std::cout << xyzzy[i] << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs (in my case):

```
59
51
84
83
58
85
83
25
50
22
```

Keep in mind that the properties of those random numbers may not be perfect due to the way they're generated but, unless you're a statistician or cryptographer, they should be fine.

Comment: @Mahi: the _only_ way? Probably not. You could probably hook up a radio telescope and use the background microwave radiation to feed your random number generator. But that seems like overkill to me - using `srand` and `rand` is the most portable way and should be more than sufficient for your needs.

Comment: this isnt that relevant but , why do you have std::cout ,contrary to just "cout<<" ?

Comment: @MahiVattekat: He didn't say `using namespace std;` therefore he has to add the `std::` to the beginning of all the stuff in that namespace, `cout` is in that namespace.

Comment: @Mahi, I'm not a big fan of `using namespace std`. That's _another_ question, one that's likely to be as violently discussed as the Apple/PC or Emacs/Vim ones :-)

Comment: Ah!I didnt notice that that's absent. Thanks!

Comment: If it ever comes to blows regarding the `using namespace` issue, count on me to back you up ;)

Answer (score 4):

In C++11

```
#include <random>

int main()
{
    int arr[10] = {0};

    std::mt19937 generator; // mersenne twister
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(6, 89);
    for(int n=0; n<10; ++n)
    {
        arr[n] = dist(generator);
    }
}
```

Comment: `uniform_int_distribution` being a template (and `int` the default parameter), I think you need `<>` at the end of the type.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Ah yes.  Thank you.  It was there originally, and in my late-night haze I made an edit to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

To get a random number from 6 - 89:

```
srand ( time(NULL) );

int randomNumber = 6 + rand() % (89 - 6 + 1);
```

Comment: so if I have to put this into an array it would go with something like 
array[x] = 6 + rand()%(89-6);

Comment: @MahiVattekat: Yeah, in a for loop or something like that.

Comment: thank you .Now it almost makes sense for what I am supposed to do

Comment: @MahiVattekat: Sorry, wait a sec, forgot to add +1 to the thing. The code is now correct.

Comment: 89 - 6 + 1 because remainders will come  from 0 to 5 , so you add + 1 so then remainders would exclude the 0 ,is that it?

Comment: @Hamhi: If you look at the code you are adding 6 to start off with, then you are finding a number within a rand of 0 - (the number you are `%`ing by - 1). So, the + 1 cancels out with the - 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <random>
#include <array>
#include <functional>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/generate.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/copy.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    //Create an array
    std::array<int, 10> arr;

    //Fill the array
    std::random_device gen;
    boost::generate(
      arr,
      std::bind(
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(6,89),
        std::ref(gen)));

    //Print the generated values
    boost::copy(arr, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n")); 
}
```